# Anyway to set 'DataContext' of a row shared by ListView Columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datacontext

That's the best way I could think of to phrase my question, here is the scenario: I have a `ListView` bound to a collection of objects. Each of those objects has a property `UserID` which is just a reference ID to a `User` object. In my `ListView` I wish to display multiple properties from both the object and the `User`. To do this I have created a class that implements `MultiValueConverter` to serve as a lookup table for the user objects. So I use a multibinding which passes the value converter the `UserID` and a dictionary look up table which is exposed by the underlying ViewModel.

This all works fine and dandy except I am hoping there is a way I could set the `DataContext` or something of the 'row' that the `ListView` columns share. In this way I could change my value converter to just return a User object instead of specific properties of the user object. And then I could just bind to the properties of that `DataContext`. I don't want to create a new value converter for each User property I wish to expose. The only other way I can think of to do this is by passing property names to value converter and using reflection.

Any ideas? I realize that this `DataContext` I am dreaming of is the job of the dataobjects bound to the `ListView`'s `ItemsSource`, but perhaps there is something else I could use too.  Attached Properties seem to solve every WPF problem I have so I am betting the solution would have to do with using an `AttachedProperty` to create this 'datacontext'

I'm sure someone will tell me to expose the User object from the dataobjects themselves instead of using some backwards method of using user ids and lookup table, BUT, I am doing this for a reason. thanks.

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.Header>User</GridViewColumn.Header>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock MinWidth="120">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UserIDConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="UserID" />
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}" Path="DataContext.Users"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

The converter:

```
public class UserIDConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int userId = (int)values[0];
        IDictionary<int, PhoneUser> table = values[1] as IDictionary<int, PhoneUser>;
        if (table.ContainsKey(userId))
        {
            PhoneUser user = table[userId];
            return user.LastName;
            //I'd like to just return user !!
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: At this point, I think my non-UI layers are just ill conceived, so I'm just going to rework them so I can use a User object reference in my data object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand you correctly, you'd like your converter to just return an entire `PhoneUser` object, then have each column decide which property of `PhoneUser` to grab?

If you're really going to insist on this convoluted method, I think your reflection idea (pass the property name into the converter and use reflection to return the value) would be best.

---

That said, I can't resist giving the answer you didn't want to hear (even if it doesn't help you, it might help someone else). Here's what I'd *really* recommend you do...

1. Create a class that combines your current object (say it's called `Foo`) and a `PhoneUser`.

   ```
   public class FooPhoneUser
   {
       Foo Foo { get; set; }
       PhoneUser User { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Use LINQ to combine these two classes together:

   ```
   var FooPhoneUsers = 
       from
           f in Foos
       join
           pu in PhoneUsers on f.UserId equals pu.Id
       select
           new FooPhoneUser { Foo = f, User = pu };
   ```
3. Get rid of all that binding markup from your `GridViewColumn`, and just put something like this:

   ```
   <TextBlock MinWidth="120" Text={Binding User.LastName} />
   ```

   or

   ```
   <TextBlock MinWidth="120" Text={Binding Foo.SomeOtherProp} />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you could populate your data object with `PhoneUser`, instead of just the ID, then you could do:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock MinWidth="120" Text="{Binding Path="User.FirstName}">
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock MinWidth="120" Text="{Binding Path="User.LastName}">
    </TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The class structure would look something like this:

```
public class myDataObject //The data object you already have.
{
    public string value1;
    public string value2;
    public PhoneUser User; //currently you have "UserID" here.
}

public class PhoneUser
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}
```

If it does not suit you to retrieve all user data when the data object is first loaded, you could use a "Lazy Loading" strategy, like this:

```
public class myDataObject //The data object you already have.
{
    public string UserID;
    public string value2;
    private PhoneUser _User; 
    public PhoneUser User
    {
        get
        {
            if(_User==null)
                _User = getUserFromDatabase(UserID);
            return _User;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe you could do this without any changes to the structure of your code.

Comment: thanks, but as stated in the question I do not want to use  a reference to the User object instance in the data object class. Thanks for trying though

Comment: Sorry - I missed that.  Can you elaborate on your reason for not wanting to do this? If I know what your requirements are based on I might be in better position to give you a good answer.  I think there has to be a better strategy than the one you're attempting.

Comment: 'better strategy', I believe your right. I'm just going to rework my other layers so I can use a User object in my data object. I think I just got caught up into trying to make this work rather than thinking of the project as a whole.

Comment: @J - I've revised my answer with some more details about Lazy Loading - this should work with the same performance and effectiveness as what your question proposed. Refactoring your code is a good idea but this might get you out of trouble :)